# Parsing a String to Option[LocalDateTime]

Tags: scala, jodatime

I wrote a `TimeFormatter` to parse a `String` to an `Option[LocalDateTime]`.

The API notes that either exception could be thrown.

```
 private def convertToDateTime(date: String): Option[LocalDateTime] =
   try {
     Some( timeFormatter.parseLocalDateTime(date) )
   }
   catch { // DateTimeFormatter#parseLocalDateTime API throws these possible exceptions
     case e @ (_: IllegalArgumentException | _: UnsupportedOperationException) =>
       log.error(s"Could not convert $date to LocalDateTime", e); None

   }
```

[Joshua Bloch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joshua_Bloch) notes:

> Item 39: Use exceptions only for exceptional conditions.

I thought of using a regular expression to catch an error. But, I'm not sure if my reg-ex will always match `jodatime`'s way of parsing the `String` to a `LocalDateTime`. I can trust that the API will throw those exceptions, but I'd rather not rely upon internals of the method call with a reg-ex.

From a functional point of view, I'd rather not use exceptions.

How can I write this function without exceptions?

Comment: So are you throwing the exception, or is joda time? If joda is throwing them, there's not a whole lot you can do.

Comment: I don't see any other alternative. Using `scala.util.Try` doesn't really help either here.

Answer (score 7):

There is nothing wrong with your code : you are not using exceptions to model non-exceptional conditions. You are handling conversion errors and turning them into a value to be returned which is perfectly acceptable.

Jodatime is using exceptions to signal invalid input (maybe not so exceptional) or the unavailability of a part of its API (completely exceptional), this is common practice in the Java world.

To actually parse dates without exceptions entirely you would need to find or reimplement a date handling library which is quite a huge endeavour.

A silent alternative to your method:

```
private def convertToDateTime(date: String): Option[LocalDateTime] = 
  Try(timeFormatter.parseLocalDateTime(date)).toOption
```

Answer (score 3):

I have experimented with Joda-Time and found this half solution **avoiding runtime exceptions** even in case of wrong input:

```
String input = "2015-02-a29 15:24:33";
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
DateTimeParser parser = dtf.getParser();
Chronology chronology = ISOChronology.getInstanceUTC();
DateTimeParserBucket bucket =
  new DateTimeParserBucket(0L, chronology, Locale.getDefault(), 2000, 2000);
int result = parser.parseInto(bucket, input, 0);
System.out.println(result);

if (result < 0) {
  System.out.println("Parsing failed at position: " + ~result);
} else {
  System.out.println(new LocalDateTime(bucket.computeMillis(), chronology));
}
```

The output is for the given input:

> -9
>
> Parsing failed at position: 8

This is in agreement with the [javadoc](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeParser.html#parseInto-org.joda.time.format.DateTimeParserBucket-java.lang.String-int-). However, the bad news is that this solution is not perfect. If you use the input `2015-02-29 15:24:33` (an invalid date in non-leap-year) then you get an exception because Joda-Time does not recognize in the method `parseInto(...)` that the parsed day-of-month is out of range and unfortunately sees it too late, namely in the method `computeMillis()`. The output is here:

```
19 // should have been negative - probably a bug!!!
Exception in thread "main" org.joda.time.IllegalFieldValueException: Value 29 for dayOfMonth must be in the range [1,28]
    at org.joda.time.field.FieldUtils.verifyValueBounds(FieldUtils.java:217)
    at org.joda.time.field.PreciseDurationDateTimeField.set(PreciseDurationDateTimeField.java:78)
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeParserBucket$SavedField.set(DateTimeParserBucket.java:483)
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeParserBucket.computeMillis(DateTimeParserBucket.java:365)
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeParserBucket.computeMillis(DateTimeParserBucket.java:318)
    at JodaPeriod.main(JodaPeriod.java:31)
```

Of course, for the valid input `2015-02-28 15:24:33` all is fine, and the output is

```
19
2015-02-28T15:24:33.000
```

I agree with Joshua Bloch that catching exceptions should only be used in exceptional situations. In my company architects say: Don't use exceptions for programming logic. Sometimes it is good for performance to avoid exceptions when ever possible in use-cases like processing a lot of possibly wrong data. A good API should therefore support similar solutions.

Note that other date-and-time-libraries have this option, too. For example `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` using an instance of class `ParsePosition` (there the API is even much simpler and smoothly works - although not thread-safe).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`Exception`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.control.Exception$) api in `scala.control` to transform exceptions:

Your function would look something like this:

```
import scala.util.control.Exception._

private def convertToDateTime(date: String): Option[LocalDateTime] =
    catching(classOf[Exception]) opt timeFormatter.parseLocalDateTime(date)
```